# changing the direction of footnotes in reledmac

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

Dear Ladies and Gentlemen,
I am sorry, I would like to ask again about reledmac: I would like to put an Arabic text facing its translation into German, thereby employing two layers of familiar footnotes, one, footnoteA, referring to the German translation, and the second, footnoteB, to the original Arabic text. Furthermore the footnoteB layer should run from right to left and should be arranged in paragraph series with the \arrangementX command. (reledmac manual p.35, subsection 7.1). This causes the footnoteB series to be set from left to right and the characters to disappear. By using the \wrapcontentX[B]{\textarabic} command (reledmac manual, p.42, sub subsection 7.7.2), the Arabic characters reappear, but the order of the words is still LTR. This can also not be changed by the \beforeinsertingX[B]{\RTL} command (see reledmac manual p.43, sub subsection 7.10).
How can the change of the direction of the footnoteB series can be achieved?

This is the code of the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[series={A,B},nocritical,noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}

\linenumincrement*{2}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.4\textwidth} 

\newcommand{
\فب
}[1]{\footnoteB{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bodyfootmarkA}{\textsuperscript{\hspace{1pt}(\@thefnmarkA)}}
\renewcommand{\bodyfootmarkB}{\textarabic{\hspace{1pt}\textsuperscript{(\@thefnmarkB)}}}
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkA}{\textsuperscript{(\@thefnmarkA)}\hspace{1ex}}
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkB}{\textarabic{\textsuperscript{(\@thefnmarkB)}}\hspace{1ex}}
\makeatother

\beforeinsertingX[B]{\RTL}
\wrapcontentX[B]{\textarabic}
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}

\begin{document}

%\numberlinefalse

\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\begin{pairs}

\begin{Rightside} 
\begin{RTL}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
نحمدك اللهمّ على نعم يؤذن\فب{يُؤْذِنُ.} الحمد بازديادها، ونصلي على نبيك محمد     هادي الأمة\فب{يعني أمة محمد.} لرشادها
\pend    
\endnumbering
\end{spacing}
\end{Arabic}
\end{RTL}
\end{Rightside}

\begin{Leftside} 
\begin{german}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent
Wir preisen dich, Gott, für Gnadengaben, deren Lobpreis von    ihrem\footnoteA{\hspace{1ex}D.h. der Gnadengaben} Anwachsen kündet, und wir bitten um Segen für deinen Propheten Muḥammad, der die Gemeinde auf den rechten Weg führt.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{german}
\end{Leftside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will answer, but please, take account of my remark after my previous answer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by parallelisme typesetting. 
When reledpar typeset columns, in `\columns`, it is on Left-to-Right mode. It can know that right content is RTL, because it read it in box stored as right-to-left, but it can't know it for footnotes, and as paragraphed footnote manipulate a lot of low-level concept of TeX, it don't know the problem.

`\beforeinsertingX` can't help you, because it concern the time footnotes are add in the list of footnotes for the current page, not the time they are typeset.

The good way is to add this thing in the preamble:

```
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
\wrapcontentX[B]{\textarabic}
\bhookgroupX[B]{\RTL}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoteruleB}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother
```

The `\bhookgroupX` content is called just before typesetting footnotes (you must call `\bhookgroupX` after the `\arrangementX`. In general, the `\arrangementX` setting must be the first one to be done.

The redefinition of `\footnoteruleB` just put the footnote rule on the good position.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very fast answer, it works fine. By the way, is there a method to change the appearance (length and thickness) of the footnote rule similar to the way of the \right@footnoterule you used to set the footnote rule right? I did not find anything in the manual.

Comment: Thats is on other question. Please open a new one. AND PLEASE validate the answer of your previous question if ok. That is required for the good use of this site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very useful answer, I have validated it, and I will open a new question.