# Killing Reledmac's footnoterule and resurrect LaTeX's one

Tags: footnotes, rules, reledmac

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355591/customising-the-footnote-rule-in-reledmac) Maïeul explains how footnoterules work in Reledmac. in the provided example there are two "standard" (namely not critical) footnotes series. Each of them can have a footnoterule, so that in a default edition we would have:

Text

\footnoteruleA

[Familiar Footenotes series A]

\footnoteruleB

[Familiar Footenotes series B]

Now, let's imagine that we want just one footnote rule separating the text from all the apparatus (regardless how many / what kind of footnotes we have in that particular page), and we can do that simply putting in our preamble:

```
\let\footnoteruleB=\relax
```

Now comes the problem. It might happen that in one or few pages we have footnotesB and no footnotesA. As a result Reledmac will print NO footnote rule at all.

So the question is: is it possible to bypass Reledmac using just the standard LaTeX `\footnoterule` making it appear regardless what kind of Reledmac series is present?

Comment: well, there is today no easy for such feature. But it could be easy to implement now hook for this case.

Comment: Please open an issue on github, with a MWE.