# Can I have one footnote ruler for 2 or more series in reledmac?

Tags: footnotes, rules, reledmac

When I have two ruler one for each footnote I have ruler, when i have only one series footnote on page. Question is is it possible to have just one ruler for A,B footnotes? No matter wat footnote i have A,B, or both only one ruler is drawn.
Here is a MnotWE :)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage{perpage}
\arrangementX{paragraph}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\MakePerPage{footnoteB}
\renewcommand\footnoteruleA{ %
\kern-3pt \hrule width 5.0cm \kern 2.6pt \par \hspace{2em}}
\renewcommand\footnoteruleB{ }
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\roman{footnoteB}}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
An footnote\footnoteA{footnoteA text}\footnoteB{footnoteB text} 
 and I don't need two rulers
\pend
\newpage
\pstart
 Some text with A footnote\footnoteA{This is ok}
  \pend
\newpage
    \pstart
 Some text with B footnote\footnoteB{I need ruler here}
  \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not yet, but it should be easy to add it. Please open a github issue.

Comment: @Maïeul: quick, slightly off topic question: does this possibility already exist for Xfootnotes? I remember it being requested some time ago here on SE, but I lost track.

Comment: @marquinho well, I don't think. I don't remmber to have coded such feature. And generally, I code in same time for both critical and familar footnote.

But MAYBE in the ANSWE to SE, I/someone found an algorithm with the already existing relesmac hook. But I don't think so.

Comment: @Maïeul I see. Just for the record: it turns out that [the old SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543428/) was a request for this very same feature (concerning \footnoteX). But it appears the user didn't open a github issue back then (I didn't find anything on github from that period) and the issue died down. This just for the record :)