# How can I hide/suppress footnote reference numbers in reledmac?

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I'm working on a project using reledmac and I'm trying to figure out how to suppress the footnote numbers, both in the text and in the footnotes themselves. I've read the question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355591/customising-the-footnote-rule-in-reledmac) but it gets pretty deep into the weeds and I have trouble following it, and as far as I CAN follow it it seems not to be completely relevant to my question. The question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) seem clearer and easier to understand, but they're about a project that isn't using reledmac.

Any thoughts about how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance, folks, for your help.

Here's an MWE:

````
\usepackage[norule,symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[nocritical,noend,series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}

\begin{document}

Ad purpureās brācās\footnoteA{\textbf{Brācæ:} Long pants.} et canāliculātās\footnoteA{\textbf{Canāliculātus:} Like a channel, channeled.}\multfootsep\footnoteB{\textbf{Brācæ canāliculātæ:} Channeled long pants; i.e., corduroy pants.} dēspexit, illāsque tālēs, quālibus indūta (aut indūtus) sībilum\footnoteA{\textbf{sībilum:} whisper.} ēdās cum ambulēs\footnoteB{\textbf{quālibus … cum ambulēs:} the kind that make a whispering sound when you walk wearing them. Both \emph{indūta} and \emph{indūtus} are used so as not to exclude the female reader.}. 

\end{document}```
````

Comment: `\footnoteA[\relax]{\textbf{Brācæ:} Long pants.}` could work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fantastic! This worked! If you turn it into an answer I'll accept it.