# New begin of footnote numbering on every page with reledmac

Tags: reledmac

I would like to ask if it is possible in `reledmac` to have familiar footnotes which begin with the number 1 on every page, as can be achieved with the package `perpage` in combination with other packages and which seems not to work with `reledmac`.

This feature is desired to work with the following minimal example where an Arabic text is facing its German translation and there are two layers of familiar footnotes, `footnoteA` referring to the LTR text and `footnoteB` referring to the RTL text:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[series={A,B},nocritical,noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\setotherlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}

\linenumincrement*{2}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.4\textwidth} 

\newcommand{
\فب
}[1]{\footnoteB{#1}}
\newcommand{
\مج
}[1]{\ledsidenote{\textarabic{#1}}}

%\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}

\afterruleX[A]{2pt}

\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
\wrapcontentX[B]{\textarabic}
\bhookgroupX[B]{\RTL}%this is the correct way to set the B-footnotes in a paragraph, the \arrangementX has to be done first, this was communicated by Maïeul Rouquette, the developer of reledmac, on Fr., the 24.02.2017, on stakexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355398/changing-the-direction-of-footnotes-in-reledmac

\afterruleX[B]{2pt}%to increase the vertical space between footnoteruleB and the B-footnotes, it has to be placed before the command which puts the B-footnoterule right

\makeatletter
\def\right@footnoterule{%
\kern-3\p@
 \hbox to \columnwidth{\hskip .9\columnwidth \leaders\hrule \@height 3\p@\hfill}
  \kern2.6\p@}
\def\left@footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width .1\columnwidth \@height 3\p@ \kern 2.6\p@}

\renewcommand{\footnoteruleA}{\left@footnoterule}
\renewcommand{\footnoteruleB}{\right@footnoterule}%to customise the footnoterules, i.e. to align them right, or to change their width and height, this solution was provided by Maïeul Rouquette on Sa. 25.02.2017 on stackexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355591/customising-the-footnote-rule-in-reledmac

%the following commands where communicated by Maïeul Rouquette, the developer of reledmac, on the Thu. the 23.02.2017 on stakexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355182/customising-footnote-marks-with-reledmac, it seems that these commands have to be set after the commands for the arrangement of the footnotes in order to implement all the details, for example the hspace after the footfootmarkA
\renewcommand{\bodyfootmarkA}{\textsuperscript{\hspace{1pt}(\@thefnmarkA)}}
\renewcommand{\bodyfootmarkB){\textarabic{\hspace{1pt}\textsuperscript{(\@thefnmarkB)}}}
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkA}{\textsuperscript{(\@thefnmarkA)}\hspace{1ex}}
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkB}{\textarabic{\textsuperscript{(\@thefnmarkB)}}\hspace{1ex}}

\makeatother

\sidenotemargin{outer}
\setlength{\ledrsnotesep}{7.5cm}
\setlength{\ledlsnotesep}{1.3cm}

\leftnoteupfalse
\rightnoteupfalse

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnoteB}

\begin{document}

%\numberlinefalse

\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\begin{pairs}

\begin{Rightside} 
\begin{RTL}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
نحمدك اللهمّ على نعم يؤذن\فب{يُؤْذِنُ}. الحمد [ص ٢]\مج{ص ٢} بازديادها، ونصلي على نبيك محمد هادي الأمة\فب{يعني أمة محمد.} لرشادها
\pend    
\endnumbering
\end{spacing}
\end{Arabic}
\end{RTL}
\end{Rightside}

\begin{Leftside} 
\begin{german}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent
Wir preisen dich, Gott, für Gnadengaben, deren Lobpreis von    ihrem\footnoteA{D.h. der Gnadengaben.} Anwachsen kündet, [p.2.]\ledsidenote{[p.2]} und\ledsidenote{[A]} wir bitten um Segen für deinen Propheten Muḥammad, der die Gemeinde auf den rechten Weg führt.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{german}
\end{Leftside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\newpage

\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\begin{pairs}

\begin{Rightside} 
\begin{RTL}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
نحمدك اللهمّ على نعم يؤذن\فب{يُؤْذِنُ.} الحمد بازديادها، ونصلي على نبيك محمد     هادي الأمة\فب{يعني أمة محمد.} لرشادها
\pend    
\endnumbering
\end{spacing}
\end{Arabic}
\end{RTL}
\end{Rightside}

\begin{Leftside} 
\begin{german}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent
Wir preisen dich, Gott, für Gnadengaben, deren Lobpreis von    ihrem\footnoteA{D.h. der Gnadengaben.} Anwachsen kündet, [p.2.]\ledsidenote{[p.2]} und\ledsidenote{[A, B, L, R, F und in verschiedenen Handschriften]} wir bitten um Segen für deinen Propheten Muḥammad, der die Gemeinde auf den rechten Weg führt.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{german}
\end{Leftside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns


\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you test it without this Arabic font content? I don't want to download peculiar fonts just in order to test this

Comment: I have removed every command which has to do with RTL and Arabic from the file, and it still does not start the footnote numbers on a new page with number 1. But anyway, I need the RTL functions.

Comment: You have writtent `\renewcommand{\bodyfootmarkB)` and not `\renewcommand{\bodyfootmarkB}`. I will answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the handbook of reledpar (p. 14)

You must use

```
 \MakePerPage{footnote@typeset}
 \MakePerPage{footnoteA@typeset}
 \MakePerPage{footnoteB@typeset}
```

Instead of

```
 \MakePerPage{footnote}
 \MakePerPage{footnoteA}
 \MakePerPage{footnoteB}
```

That is because reledpar does not use directly the footnote counter, as explained on § 6.2.3 of the handbook.

Why ?

Because these counters are increased when the content of `pairs` environment  is read, which does not necessary correspond to the order they are typeset in `\Columns`, as you may use the same footnote layer for both side.

In your case, that multiply the number of runs need (5 for me). You must use latexmk to be sur to make the correct number of run

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine. Thank you very much also for directing me to the relevant information in the reledpar manual.